# Draw Objects on Mouse Click Using Two Viewports on OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, viewport, mouseover, viewport3d

I'm trying to render a polygon on mouse click in my opengl program but I'm having problems with it. Basically it works when I use one viewport, but when I try to put two viewports the square doesn't appear in the right position anymore. The mouse function which calculates the right position is the GMouse above.

```
void GMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
       if (state == GLUT_DOWN) { // Zoom-in
           y=250-y;
           m=1;
           posX=x;
           posY=y;
       }
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON)
       if (state == GLUT_DOWN) { // Zoom-out      
           if (angle <= 130) angle += 5;
       }

    visao();    
    glutPostRedisplay();    
}
```

I'm using y = 250-y because the width of the viewports is 250, but the window size is (500,500) and the InitWindowPosition is (0,0) as stated in the view() function above.

```
void view(){    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    
    defineIluminacao();    
    glMatrixMode(GL_VIEWPORT);       
    glViewport(0,100,250,250);    
    visao();    
    display(); 
    glViewport(300,0,200,200);    
    visao2();    
    glTranslatef(-30.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f);    
    glRotated(90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);    
    display();
}
```

Comment: There is no `GL_VIEWPORT` matrix mode.

Comment: You should check for OpenGL errors using `glGetError()`